# Switch fragment like Nav drawer does (with back arrow)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an application and I'm struggling on a problem.
I want to get from "Accueil" (home) to for exemple "Depense" (Expense) by a button click.
As you may check in the gif (at end of post), if I do so by the menu, i've got a back arrow on top. And, If i go from home to "Avance" (Advance), i've got the menu icon.

I manage to find out where this come from, I use the standard navigation drawer and If i add my fragment in is code I've got the menu, if not, i've got the arrow.

```
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_avance)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
```

R.id.nav_avance is in but R.id.depense is not. That's why i've got the arrow.

I'm trying to make the same as the standard drawer does when I click but I can't manage to do so.
I've tried this for the moment in my "Accueil" (home) fragment code :

```
        Button b = root.findViewById(R.id.player_1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new DepenseFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
                ft.commit();
           }
    });
```

But If i click on the button, the new fragment appear BUT .. I've got the menu icon on top, and the old text which is "Accueil" and not "Depense".

Could you please help me achieve this ?
For information, I want, in this new fragment, a number according to the button I've click.
For example, if I click player_1, I want to pass 1.. player_2 pass 2 to the new fragment etc.

Thanks for your help :)

[image: desc image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here come my own answer after (few) hours of research and try.

```
        Button b = root.findViewById(R.id.player_1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder();
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(root);

                NavOptions options = builder.build();
                try {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_joueur, null, options);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                }
        }
    });
```

I have found that the drawer use the navigation controler in order to change the displayed fragment.
I've manage to get it and change it in order to get the same behavior as is I click on the menu :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no "build-in" solution, i.e., you have to manually manipluate/update the icon in the `ActionBar` when you click on your button. Hence, I would add the following code to your `onClick()` method:

```
ActionBar actionbar = this.getSupportActionBar();
if (actionbar != null) {
    // get the drawable which you want to show
    Drawable icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_white_24);

    // if necessary, adapt it to your theme
    icon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    // set/update the icon
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Please note that `this` refers to your activity object, so you have to adapt that part. As I don't know "where" `b` is located I can only guess how you have to adapt it. For example if `b` is already in your Activity you might replace `this` with `MainActivity.this`.

If `this.getSupportActionBar()` returns null, you might to adapt your XML layout. Please see here as a starting point:
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Please look here for a detailed description of the used methods (e.g., `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar

Please note that the drawable above comes from here (both icons are available):
https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have been trying other method in order to achieve what I want and I came up with a solution. I will share it in this question